# Need a Formula or Conditional Formatting rule to apply dynamically to table when filters change

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have a large table, 1300+ rows and up to AS columns.  This table has groups of Job numbers and I use conditional formatting to put a line between each set of lines for each job.  So, lines 4 to 18 is job 21-3166 and lines 19 to 25 is job 21-3167.  I put a line between rows 17 and 18 to visually see the segration of the job.

Right now I have a formula in a row that indicates if the row above has a different job number and if it does, make the cell value 1, if not make it -1.  This way, the conditional formatting looks for the rows that are different (1 vs -1) and draws a line between the two.  I use the offset function so that when the data is sorted differently it maintains looking at the rows directly above or below within that sort.

Each job has many lines of milestones that are number 1, 2, 3 etc. Example of 21-3166 is 3 lines per milestone, so 6 milestones.

Sometime I filter the data to show only specific data (it changes depending on my needs of the day) and I'll do something like show only Milestone 3 for ALL jobs.

My problem is that milestone 3 is not the top or bottom of the job (rows 4 to 18) so the lines between each job no longer show.

How can I formulate the 1 vs -1 column to look at only the new filtered data?  I need this to be dynamic as I change how I'm looking at things throughout the day. This is used to track up to a hundred different jobs and 1-12 milestone each.

I'm using Office 365
Thanks!

Comment: `Right now I have a formula... ` What is this formula? Sample data and expected outcome would also be nice

Comment: Could you reference your data with `FILTER()`?

Comment: [edit] your post & Share some screen shot as well the formula U have applied so far,,, will help us to understand the issue to fix it ☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible solution.

Create a helper column with a formula like this:

```
=IF(SUBTOTAL(103,[@Job])=1,[@Job],"")
```

This formula says "Count the non-hidden text values (indicated by [sub-total 103](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/subtotal-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939)) in the current row (indicated by `@`) of the `Job` column. If there is 1 non-hidden text, the row is not hidden, so return the Job from the current row. If there are zero non-hidden text, the row is hidden, so return an empty string".

Call that column 'HiddenJob'.

Now change your ConditionalFormatter column to:

```
=[@HiddenJob] <>
    XLOOKUP(
        1,
        (ROW([HiddenJob]) < ROW([@Job])) * ([HiddenJob] <> ""),
        [HiddenJob],
        [@Job],
        ,
        -1
    )
```

`(ROW([HiddenJob]) < ROW([@Job])) * ([HiddenJob] <> "")` creates an array of 1s and 0s. The array is 1 where the row number is less than the current row and the HiddenJob column is not blank.

`XLOOKUP` searches said array from last to first (indicated by `-1` at the end) and stops where it finds 1. This is the first non-blank row in HiddenJob above the current row.

The inequality is therefore comparing whether the current row's job number is not equal to the job number of the first non-hidden row above the current row.

When not filtered, where the job number changes, the conditional formatter column shows TRUE as in cell D11:

[image]

And when filtered to Milestone=2 in cell D14:

[image]

Or even when Milestone = 1 or 3 the change is only in cell D11:

[image]

To avoid confusion, you can hide the HiddenJob helper column.

Comment: Thanks, that's a big chuck to digest, I'll look at that and see if I can follow it and get it working.  I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: OK. No worries. btw I've updated the images as I noticed they were using an older version of a formula I tried.

Comment: THANK YOU.... that was brilliant, and easy.  I didn't realize how easy it was until I started working through it.  Wicked!

Comment: Glad to hear it. I prefer to include detail in answers so it starts off by looking more complicated than it actually is.